# Binding a table foreign key headers into a dropdown list in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.0

I'm new in implementing a project with asp.net core. I want to create a dropdownlist in a view that has foreign keys of a table as its items in SQL server and the table has related model in Visual studio. I appreciate if anyone guide me how I can do this?

Comment: The following is a great guide to get a simple Asp.Net Core project quickly up and running: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-aspnet-core?view=vs-2019 When you have it up and running, post me a comment and we can move on creating the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You can use SelectList (part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering) for this. Suppose you have two db tables table1 and table2, table1 primary key is forigen key in table2. In your custom viewmodel which you have for holding rows of table2 include SelectList like this.

public SelectList Table1List { get; set; }

and to fill the SelectList with the rows of table1 you can write this code from where you are returning table2 viewmodel to bind a page.

table2ViewModel.Table1List = new SelectList(yourservicetogetdata.GetTable1Data(), "Id", "ColumnName");

And in the View bind the dropdownlist like this.

@Html.DropDownList("dropdownlistId", (SelectList)Model.Table1List))